# nginx redirect httP://WWW.example to httPS://example (SSL/HTTPS and to NON-WWW)

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx, web, https

I am trying to get

1. `http://www.domain`
2. `https://www.domain`
3. `http:// domain`
4. `https:// domain`

to all redirect to 4. `https://domain`

3 and 4 both end up at 4.

1 and 2 - do not end up at 4.

I also tried to do the www to non-www redirect using an s3 bucket and cloudfront, but unfortunately, this causes certificate issues.

Here is what I currently have in my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.{{ nginx_server_name }} {{ nginx_server_name }};
    return 301 https://{{ nginx_server_name }}$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name www.{{ nginx_server_name }}

  ssl on;
  charset utf-8;
  ssl_certificate     {{ certbot_output_dir }}/{{ letsencrypt_cert_filename }};
  ssl_certificate_key {{ certbot_output_dir }}/{{ letsencrypt_privkey_filename }};
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         'ECDHE-..........
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  return 301 https://{{ nginx_server_name }}$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443;
    server_name         {{ nginx_server_name }};
    ssl on;
    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate     {{ certbot_output_dir }}/{{ letsencrypt_cert_filename }};
    ssl_certificate_key {{ certbot_output_dir }}/{{ letsencrypt_privkey_filename }};

    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers         'ECDHE-..........
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Answer (score 0):

You config seems correct, but are those parameters?
Maybe this works for you:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This will forward all the http requests to www.example.com and example.com to https://example.com you should then also create a listener on https with host name www.example.com to forward the same way.
So not using the parameters, or was that because of obfuscation?

Comment: Hi Stephan
The parameters are ansible variables
    nginx_server_name: domain.com

Also, will the second server block not do what you described?
i.e. will these few lines listen on https with hostname www.domain.com

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name www.{{ nginx_server_name }}
  ssl on;

Comment: If you specify the domain in the return 301... line, it fixes your problem. Because it is a parameter it will always match.